# Can we connect sql server databases using SPN in databricks using scala?

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, sqlconnection

My use case is to connect to the SQL server using SPN credentials in Databricks notebook. Since I don't have username password and can't generate access token so I have to do it with the help of SPN only. I couldn't find anything until now.
Please help how to do it if anyone has done it before or has an idea about it. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/spark-connector#connecting-using-an-access-token - you mean access token?

Comment: What do you mean by SPN? Do you mean service principal name? I believe that's a Kerberos / on-prem thing so highly unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to do that and it's described in the [repository of sql-spark-connector connector](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector#azure-active-directory-authentication) and in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/spark-connector#connecting-using-an-access-token). The prerequisite is installation of the [azure-activedirectory-library-for-java library](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java).  After both dependencies are installed, following code should work:

```py
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority)
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(
      resource_app_id_url, service_principal_id, service_principal_secret)
access_token = token["accessToken"]

jdbc_db = spark.read \
        .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
        .option("url", url) \
        .option("dbtable", table_name) \
        .option("accessToken", access_token) \
        .option("encrypt", "true") \
        .option("hostNameInCertificate", "*.database.windows.net") \
        .load()
```

Comment: How would one obtain the value of `resource_app_id_url` in the above code snippet?

Comment: it's the id of application for service principal

Comment: This is python code. Is there a Scala version ?

Comment: Scala version is almost identical, some difference is in function names